# Manipulating Core Location data manually

Tags: ios, swift

I'v made a Autopilot for my boat, with is controlled by an app. Is it possible to use the location data from the autopilot and manipulate Core Location data, so that other app's can use the location?
For example on a iPad WiFi without GPS?
I know BadElf has made a external GPS for iOS devices ([BadElf GPS Pro 2200](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Bad-Elf-GPS-Pro-2200-GPS-Receiver-Bluetooth-Data-Logger-for-5-Apple-iPhone-iPad/252351616832?epid=691403468&hash=item3ac1541740:g:eIYAAOSwq19XCzuG)), so it must be possible somehow.

My app is communicating via Bluetooth LE, I don't know if the BadElf device is using regular Bluetooth.

Comment: As the duplicate question states: yes, it is technically possible, but not for you :/

Comment: I just hoped that Apple had loosened up a bit on this, like they have on the NFC reader and other stuff.

Comment: No, that is a completely different ballpark. They should not open up GPS because then GPS spoofing becomes easily possible. Right now you can *trust* the GPS data to some extent, other than on Android for example.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you would have to have a MFI license to do this?

Comment: Get in touch with Apple if you want more information.